# Getting a list of AD Groups a user is in

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have this;

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> authgroups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> userGroups = user.GetGroups();
```

And it works to a point.  However the groups I am getting back don't really look like what I was expecting.

Using `gpresult /V` from the command prompt gives me a list that looks something like;

```
    BUILTIN\Administrators
    Everyone
    SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser$ITVN1259
    BUILTIN\Users
```

But using the code gives me;

```
Name ( "zz.Enterprise Vault Users Group 3" )
Name ( "CM-InternetAccessUsers(C)-SZ" )
```

How do I get the same list as gpresult does?

Comment: have you tried this out? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this - I think you're only missing the `SamAccountName` part:

```
    public string[] Groups
    {
        get { return UserPrincipal.Current.GetAuthorizationGroups()
                                          .Select(e => e.SamAccountName)
                                          .ToArray(); }
    }
```

**EDIT** : Use `GetAuthorizationGroups()` instead of `GetGroups()` for a recursive search (only returns *security* groups, not *distribution* groups).

Comment: This is still returning the incorrect list of groups though at this point I think I may have been given incorrect information to begin with so I think these groups are good.  I like your answer as it is simple and returns a list of names and not objects so thank you and +1